# Uploading image to s3 bucket from node.js with AWS SDK for JavaScript V3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I'm facing issues uploading images to an S3 bucket from Node.js. I'm just now learning to work with AWS. The following error is shown while installing the `aws-sdk` module.

> (node:23844) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for
> JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.
>
> Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3). For more
> information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy (Use
> `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Can anyone help me with the code for uploading the image to an S3 bucket?

I was trying to create an S3 constructor and defining `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`. Specifically, I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XC5rdgxyioY&list=PPSV) for linking to AWS.

Can anyone help me to meet my requirement using SDK v3?

Comment: Unless you're knowledgeable about S3 and multer, I would suggest that you not use multer right now. Learn how to use the native AWS JavaScript SDK v3 directly. There are a number of documented [S3 examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the AWS SDK for JavaScript V3, refer to this documentation for all of the details that you need.

[Getting started in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html)

I went through this yesterday and it works.

[image]

Sample code to try. Replace the name of the bucket.

```
import { S3Client, CreateBucketCommand,PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
// Set the AWS Region.
const REGION = "us-east-1"; //e.g. "us-east-1"
// Create an Amazon S3 service client object.
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: REGION });
export { s3Client };

// Set the parameters
const params = {
  Bucket: "MyBucket", // The name of the bucket. For example, 'sample-bucket-101'.
  Key: "sample_upload.txt", // The name of the object. For example, 'sample_upload.txt'.
  Body: "Hello world!", // The content of the object. For example, 'Hello world!".
};

const run = async () => {
  // Create an Amazon S3 bucket.

  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(
        new CreateBucketCommand({ Bucket: params.Bucket })
    );
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Successfully created a bucket called ", data.Location);
    return data; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }


  // Create an object and upload it to the Amazon S3 bucket.
  try {
    const results = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
    console.log(
        "Successfully created " +
        params.Key +
        " and uploaded it to " +
        params.Bucket +
        "/" +
        params.Key
    );
    return results; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }

};
run();
// snippet-end:[GettingStarted.JavaScript.NodeJS.sampleV3]
// For unit tests.
// module.exports = {run, params};
```

My creds are located in .aws/credentials as discussed here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

After you get this code working, try to upload other content such as images.

Comment: Hey @smac2020, while i was going through the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html , this part says that the SDK automatically detects AWS credentials set as variables in your environment and uses them for SDK requests. So do you have any idea how is that works?

Comment: Yes - you can setup Environment variables on your machine, For example I am on Windows and setup AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: I will work on this and update the status once it's done

Comment: Sir, i have uploaded the image to s3 bucket. But since I'm using SDK for javascript v3, i'm not able to get the link to image. Is there any method to retrieve link to s3 bucket after uploading? If you could help me, please answer it in my another question. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77184519/unable-to-get-the-public-link-to-s3-bucket-object-after-uploading-from-node-js