# Unable to get the public link to s3 bucket object after uploading from node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multer

I was trying to upload an image from node.js server to s3 bucket with the help of `multer` and `@aws-sdk/client-s3`. I'm using `aws-sdk` for `javascript v3`. When i use `aws-sdk` for javacript v2, I'm able to get the link to uploaded image using `Location` attribute. But when using v3, Location attribute is not present in the result object i get.

```
[
  {
    '$metadata': {
      httpStatusCode: 200,
      requestId: 'REQUEST ID',
      extendedRequestId: 'ID HERE',
      cfId: undefined,
      attempts: 1,
      totalRetryDelay: 0
    },
    ETag: '"EFTAG HERE"',
    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
  }
]
```

Is there any functions or any other method to get the link to uploaded image?

My purpose is to store image in s3 bucket and save its link to `mongoDB` database.

Here's the code I'm using for uploading the image to s3  bucket. `files` contains the array of images from `multer`. Whenever each image is uploaded using `putObjectCommand`, i want to return its url also.

```
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3")
const uuid = require("uuid").v1;;

exports.s3Uploadv3 = async (files) => {
    const s3client = new S3Client();
  
    const params = files.map((file) => {
      return {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `uploads/${uuid()}-${file.originalname}`,
        Body: file.buffer,
      };
    });
  
    return await Promise.all(
      params.map((param) => s3client.send(new PutObjectCommand(param)))
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `Location` key is exposed in `aws-sdk` (v2), but not in `@aws-sdk/client-s3`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to solve it by just using `@aws-sdk/client-s3`.

You can solve this by using [`@aws-sdk/lib-storage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html) along with `@aws-sdk/client-s3`.

This exposes the `Location` key, which is the public url of your file in S3.

```
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { Upload } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-storage");
const uuid = require("uuid").v1;

exports.s3Uploadv3 = async (files) => {
    return await Promise.all(
        files.map((file) => {
            const client = new Upload({
                client: new S3Client({}),
                params: {
                    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                    Key: `uploads/${uuid()}-${file.originalname}`,
                    Body: file.buffer,
                },
            });

            return client.done()
        })
    )
}
```

---

`client` is how you normally create your `S3Client` object. If you need to pass any extra arguments to the constructor, you can pass that.

Comment: Hi there, i have updated my question and added code I'm using for uploading the image to s3 bucket. Can you please check the code and help me to meet my requirement?

Comment: That works. so that can i send the url to frontend using re.send({" url : response.Location"})? When i try to do so I'm getting undefined

Comment: @UnnikrishnanKJ That seems like a different question. Can you create another question with code for your request handler, and add it as a comment here? I'll check it.